# AUTOMATIZAR BORRADO DE DATOS MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Tengo 2 tablas con los datos que se visualizan:

**Tabla equipos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla registro_actual**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo quiero es que cuando se alcance la fecha_fin, se borre automáticamente esa fila sin que yo tenga que hacer nada.

Estuve probando con un evento que llame a un procedimiento, pero no consigo crear el procedimiento.
En el procedimiento he declarado las variables varchar porque no quiero coger los segundos, ya que el evento quiero que se ejecute cada minuto sin tener en cuenta los segundos.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE obtener_fechasdefin ()
BEGIN
    DECLARE W71, W72, W73 VARCHAR(70);
    DECLARE FECHA_ACTUAL VARCHAR(70);
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-',MONTH(CURDATE()),'-',DAY(CURDATE()),' ',HOUR (NOW()),':',MINUTE(NOW())) INTO FECHA_ACTUAL;

    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(fecha_fin),'-',MONTH(fecha_inicio),'-',DAY(fecha_inicio),' ',HOUR (fecha_inicio),':',MINUTE(fecha_inicio)) 
        INTO W71 FROM registro_actual WHERE ID_equipo=(SELECT ID FROM equipos WHERE hostname='W7-1');
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(fecha_fin),'-',MONTH(fecha_inicio),'-',DAY(fecha_inicio),' ',HOUR (fecha_inicio),':',MINUTE(fecha_inicio)) 
        INTO W72 FROM registro_actual WHERE ID_equipo=(SELECT ID FROM equipos WHERE hostname='W7-2');
    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(fecha_fin),'-',MONTH(fecha_inicio),'-',DAY(fecha_inicio),' ',HOUR (fecha_inicio),':',MINUTE(fecha_inicio))
        INTO W73 FROM registro_actual WHERE ID_equipo=(SELECT ID FROM equipos WHERE hostname='W7-3');

    IF W71=FECHA_ACTUAL THEN
        DELETE FROM REGISTRO_ACTUAL WHERE fecha_fin REGEXP 'W71*';
    ELSE IF W72=FECHA_ACTUAL THEN
        DELETE FROM REGISTRO_ACTUAL WHERE fecha_fin REGEXP 'W72*';
    ELSE IF W73=FECHA_ACTUAL THEN
        DELETE FROM REGISTRO_ACTUAL WHERE fecha_fin REGEXP 'W73*';
    END IF;
END //

CREATE EVENT borrar_registroactual
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP EVERY 60 SECONDS DO
CALL obtener_fechasdefin ();
```

Exportación base de datos:

```
-- MariaDB dump 10.19  Distrib 10.4.24-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: conexiones
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   10.4.24-MariaDB

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

CREATE DATABASE conexiones;
USE conexiones;

--
-- Table structure for table `equipos`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `equipos`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `equipos` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hostname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `equipos`
--

LOCK TABLES `equipos` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `equipos` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `equipos` VALUES (1,'W7-1','192.168.0.1'),(2,'W7-2','192.168.0.2'),(3,'W7-3','192.168.0.3'),(29,'W7-ADMINISTRADOR','192.168.0.29');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `equipos` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `registro_actual`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `registro_actual`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `registro_actual` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_equipo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_inicio` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `fecha_fin` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `ID_equipo` (`ID_equipo`),
  CONSTRAINT `registro_actual_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_equipo`) REFERENCES `equipos` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `registro_actual`
--

LOCK TABLES `registro_actual` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `registro_actual` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `registro_actual` VALUES (1,3,'2022-04-11 20:56:41','2022-04-12 21:00:00');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `registro_actual` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Table structure for table `registro_historico`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `registro_historico`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `registro_historico` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ID_equipo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_inicio` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `fecha_fin` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `ID_equipo` (`ID_equipo`),
  CONSTRAINT `registro_historico_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_equipo`) REFERENCES `equipos` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `registro_historico`
--

LOCK TABLES `registro_historico` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `registro_historico` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `registro_historico` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2022-04-25 10:33:00
```

Comment: dame un momento y te hecho un cable por favor pon los creates table con los insert

Comment: Que grande otra vez Javier jajaj

Comment: termino con la comida y vengo @Adrián xD

Comment: yo para esto usaría un trigger que cada vez que se actualice esa tabla compruebe que si la fecha fin es igual a la fecha actual y si es el caso que se borre automática @Adrián

Answer (score 0):

***1.*** Te recomiendo que cuando vallas a modificar las tablas en lugar de borrarlas, borra la base de datos `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS conexiones;` y te ahorraría todos esos `DROP tables`

***2.*** Si quieres que cuando se modifique la fecha esta compruebe que si la fecha inicio es igual a la fecha final pues te recomiendo un trigger que eso lo hace de modo automático

***3.*** Un procedimiento no es muy eficiente para este caso ya que cada vez que lo quieras comprobar tendrás que ejecutarlo con el call mientras que con el trigger cuando se actualice la fecha, se comprobara si ha alcanzado esa fecha fin.

**Solución :**

```
USE almacen;
DELIMITER $$
DROP trigger IF EXISTS borraFecha $$
CREATE trigger borraFecha BEFORE UPDATE on registro_actual
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.fecha_inicio = OLD.fecha_fin) THEN
        DELETE FROM REGISTRO_ACTUAL WHERE NEW.fecha_fin REGEXP 'W7*';
     END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Ahora esto Debes adaptarlo a tu caso.

[<kbd>Ejecutar Prueba</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/250)

Comment: Gracias, voy a probarlo

Comment: de nada ya no te veo hasta las 6 hora española que me voy a clase

Comment: Ok. Gracias de todas formas, pero he pensado que en mi caso no sirve, ya que el insert se hace mediante un formulario PHP y en principio las filas no se van a modificar, así que creo que con el trigger no se tiene esto en cuenta

Comment: Entonces donde pones create trigger nombre before update cambialo por insert no lo tuve en cuenta pero te vale

Comment: @Adrián toma esto para que veas como funciona : https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/529961/188518

Comment: Más o menos ya sabía como iban, pero gracias por dedicarle un post a ello

Comment: De nada amigo @Adrián